# two radio checked redirect to specific link.

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to redirect when each radio checked from both questions.
but the following code i have used is not working.

```
    function chekcSubmitType()
    {

        if(document.getElementById('ra').checked, document.getElementById('rc').checked)
        {
            window.location="page-1.html"; 
        }

        if(document.getElementById('ra').checked, document.getElementById('rd').checked)
        {
            window.location="page-2.html"; 
        }

        if(document.getElementById('rb').checked, document.getElementById('rc').checked)
        {
            window.location="page-3.html"; 
        }

        if(document.getElementById('rb').checked, document.getElementById('rd').checked)
        {
            window.location="page-4.html"; 
        }
    }
```

I have separated the both question by using a JavaScript code.

```
<form name="myquiz" method="post">

<p>Question (1)</p>
        <span>500</span>
        <input type="radio" id="ra" value="question1"/>
        <span>1000</span>
        <input type="radio" id="rb" value="question1"/>

<!--I have separated these both by using a JavaScript code-->

<p>Question (2)</p>
        <span>1500</span>
        <input type="radio" id="rc" value="question2"/>
        <span>2000</span>
        <input type="radio" id="rd" value="question2"/>

<input type="button" onClick="chekcSubmitType()" value="Go" />

</form>
```

here is what i actually want to do:

(r) is stand for radio

```
ra + rc redirect to page-1.html
ra + rd redirect to page-2.html
rb + rc redirect to page-3.html
rb + rd redirect to page-4.html
```

Comment: A good way to debug JavaScript code is to use the JavaScript console provided by most good browsers, or the [FireBug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` operator...

Also make use of `else if` to make your code better...

```
function chekcSubmitType() {

if (document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rc').checked) {
    window.location = "page-1.html";
}

else if (document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rd').checked) {
    window.location = "page-2.html";
}

else if (document.getElementById('rb').checked && document.getElementById('rc').checked) {
    window.location = "page-3.html";
}

else if (document.getElementById('rb').checked && document.getElementById('rd').checked) {
    window.location = "page-4.html";
}
}​
```

Here is [demo](http://jsbin.com/uhecuw/4)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether 2 expressions are true, use the `&&`-operator, do not use a `,` to separate them:

```
function chekcSubmitType()     {
    if(document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rc').checked) {
        window.location="page-1.html"; 
    }

    if(document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rd').checked) {
        window.location="page-2.html"; 
    }
    // and so on...
}
```

See this additional information on [logical operators](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Vegar is right about the && operator, also you should be using the window.location.href='' instead of window.location.  (Some browsers need the .href to work)

```
function checkSubmitType()
{
    if(document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rc').checked)
        window.location.href = 'page-1.html';
    if(document.getElementById('ra').checked && document.getElementById('rd').checked)
        window.location.href = 'page-2.html';
    if(document.getElementById('rb').checked && document.getElementById('rc').checked)
        window.location.href = 'page-3.html';
    if(document.getElementById('rb').checked && document.getElementById('rd').checked)
        window.location.href = 'page-4.html';
}
```